# What rules to use on Firebase-RealtimeDatabase to let users register and login?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In order to let Android users register and login through my app I have set the ***.read*** and ***.write*** as ***true***. My problem is anyone is able to access the users JSON file since it's **public**. How can I **restrict the access** to the database only through the app and Firebase console? Below are the rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

You'll give `read` and `write` access only to authenticated users. For more information, please see the official documentation regarding [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

According to your comment, you should then verify if the user that performs an operation is actually the authenticated user. So for example, let's say you want only authenticated users to able to access their accounts, the following rules are required:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i use these rules, I get this message: "Your security rules are not secure. Any authenticated user can steal, modify, or delete data in your database."

Comment: In this case, you should definetly implement [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and use the rules as in my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad with that duplicate if.

Comment: @AndréKool Copy and paste it from Firestore tab. Just updated my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: If you have a problem with this rules try to delete "users" section. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This is depends on the situation of your project on how it works, If you want all authenticated users can read all users data, but cannot write to other users Database, this must be the rule. Current user can only write to his own Database

```
{
  "rules": {
   "users" : {
     ".read" : "auth != null",
       "$user_id" : {
     ".write" : "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Rule below is for: Read and write to your own Database (No one can read and write except the currentUser)

```
{
  "rules": {
   "users" : {
     "$user_id" : {
        ".read" : "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    },
  }
}
```