# I want my users to have there own database and store their data in realtime database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible for me to let users have different accounts in my Realtime Database, because they don't like my app as it only shared the same server or database? I want to create something that individual users have their own server in my Firebase. Please give me some tips that I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite usual to create a new database for each user. What you should do, is to create a node in the Firebase Realtime Database for each user. Your schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- name: "Jin Appsdev"
            |
            --- email: "Jin.Appsdev@email.com"
            |
            --- //Other fields.
```

Then you can secure it using my answer from the following post:

- [What rules to use on Firebase-RealtimeDatabase to let users register and login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114203/what-rules-to-use-on-firebase-realtimedatabase-to-let-users-register-and-login)

Comment: You're very welcome, Jin.